# swift move UIButton up in VC stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I wonder how I can move a UIButton up in the VC stack?

My problem:

In my VC I am adding a page controller view in order to swipe between images. But the problem is when I do that the button gets stuck behind the added page controller view.

My VC looks like:
[image]

My code when adding the page view controller:

```
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

This will result in the button not showing / stuck behind the page view controller.

I've already tried to add a second UIView under the root view and the button before that view then adding the page view controller as subview to that new view by : `self.MyNewSubView.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)`

That almost works. The button is showing in front of the page view controller but the autolayout gets messed up for the page view controller since it containts a uiscroll view with a image (zoom in/out).

I also tried to set the CGRectMake to eg CGRectMake(0,50) that kinda works. But problem there is big images in portrait getting clipped at the bottom.

So what I would want to do is to pushing the button up the stack once I added the page view controller.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask your current view to bringSubviewToFront(button)

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I was looking for